# the last iteration in a while loop

Tags: php, while-loop

I'm trying to get the last item in an array, when being iterated to output something different to a string.

```
if (count($this->condition) > 1) {
        $i=0;
        while ($i < count($this->condition)){
            if ($i == (count($this->condition) -1)) {

                foreach ($this->condition as $key => $value){

                    $query .= $value['columns']." = ".$value['value'];
                }
            } else {
                foreach ($this->condition as $key => $value){

                    $query .= $value['columns']." = ".$value['value']." AND ";
                    $i++;

                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        foreach ($this->condition as $key => $value){
            $query .= $value['columns']." = ".$value['value'];

        }
    }
```

However, it keeps adding the AND, meaning that `$i == (count($this->condition))` is never true.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Sounds like you would be better off using `implode()`

Comment: Hi @Mike, how would I use implode in this situation - a day on PHP on a Saturday isn't my cup of tea!

Comment: Why do you keep counting?  You should put that into a var and then use the var to get the value.

Comment: From what it looks like, you just want to insert "AND" between each of the values returned. So instead of checking whether it's the last one, just do something like `implode(' AND ', $strings)`

Comment: Hi Mike, the small problem is that the array looks like `Array ([0]=> Array([0]Array(['column'] = ['value'])))`if that make sense?

Comment: Change this line:
while ($i < count($this->condition)){
to:
while ($i <= count($this->condition)){

The issue you are having is that your while will never allow $i to equal the count.  So therefore your $i == statement will never be processed

Comment: @DavidGuerra, having changed that, two arrays are repeating itself

Comment: Now just move this $i++; outside that else statement and you are good to go.

Comment: @DavidGuerra, there's more duplication if I move it outside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it.

```
 if (count($this->condition) > 1) {
            $i=0;
            foreach ($this->condition as $key => $value){

                if ($i == ($conditionCount -1)) {
                    $query .= $value['columns']." = ".$value['value'];
                } else {
                    $query .= $value['columns']." = ".$value['value']." AND ";
                }
            $i++;
            }
    } else {
        foreach ($this->condition as $key => $value){
            $query .= $value['columns']." = ".$value['value'];

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

By far simpler method is to build an array of conditions, then `implode` them at the end.

```
$conditions = array();
foreach($this->condition as $key => $value) {
   $conditions[] = $values['columns'] . ' = ' . $value['value'];
}
$query = implode(' and ', $conditions);
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in PHP are zero-based. If `count()` returns `n`, then the last element in your array can be accessed at the `n-1`th index.

Hence:

`if ($i == (count($this->condition)))`

should be

`if ($i == (count($this->condition) - 1))`

Also, you are incrementing `$i` too often. `$i++` should be moved outside the `foreach` loop. It should be like this:

```
while ($i < count($this->condition)) {
    if ($i == (count($this->condition) -1)) {
        foreach ($this->condition as $key => $value){
            $query .= $value['columns']." = ".$value['value'];
        }
    } else {
        foreach ($this->condition as $key => $value){
            $query .= $value['columns']." = ".$value['value']." AND ";
        }

        $i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Shamil: Updated my post. Try that out.

Comment: having it inside the if kills the script, whilst having it outside produces two of the array being iterated again.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way: your if should be

```
 if ($i == count($this->condition)-1) {
```

as arrays are 0-indexed.

The even simpler way, though - as your code runs out of the while, $i will still be set. Why don't you read it after the while is done, and substract one?