# Removing last comma from a anchor link?

Tags: php, html

I'm currently working on a code that retrieves the first names and last names from a database and adds a link to other pages using an anchor link. This is the code:

```
<?php
$get_names_query_result = $get_names_query->get_result();
if (!$get_names_query_result) {
   xecho("Names query failed.");
   } else {
    while ($name = $get_names_query_result->fetch_assoc()) {
?>
    <a href="personDetails.php?id=<?php xecho($name['pID']) ?>"><?php xecho($name['first_name']) ?> <?php xecho($name['last_name']) ?></a>,
<?php
   } // while fetch_assoc()
} // if $get_names_query_result
```

This code displays this on the webpage:

[code-commas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTpFr.png)

I would like to eliminate that trailing comma at the end of the last element but I'm pretty lost on how to do it only for the name shown.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [the last iteration in a while loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13436414/the-last-iteration-in-a-while-loop)

Comment: An alternative would be to use `implode`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach I use is to create a variable, say $comma, and initialise it as  "". Then after its first use, which adds nothing to your output, change it to ",". SO...

```
<?php
$comma = "";
$get_names_query_result = $get_names_query->get_result();
if (!$get_names_query_result) {
   xecho("Names query failed.");
   } else {
    while ($name = $get_names_query_result->fetch_assoc()) {
?>
    <?php echo $comma; ?> <a href="personDetails.php?id=<?php xecho($name['pID']) ?>"><?php xecho($name['first_name']) ?> <?php xecho($name['last_name']) ?></a>
<?php
    $comma = "," 
   } // while fetch_assoc()
} // if $get_names_query_result
```

Note that the comma is now added before the anchor, not after it as you had it.

Comment: I try doing what you suggested but it's not showing any commas

Comment: Sorry @CatalinaOtarola, I missed the "echo" where the comma is rendered - I have added it to my code. Give that a try.

Comment: BTW, what is xecho - is that a function you have written?

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much :) I spent a while trying to fix that little comma, so this was really useful. I believe xecho is a function previously written. I'm working with files I didn't create but I'm pretty sure that's what it is. Thank you again!